# Using SQL function in parameterized statement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Considering this query:

```
insert (a, b, update_time) values (1, 1, now() - interval 10 second)
```

Now, I need to convert it to a parameterized statement:

```
insert (a, b, update_time) values (?, ?, ?)
```

The problem is you cannot use SQL function in the parameter. How do I write this kind of code?

Comment: You could calculate it using Java code ?

Comment: never mind. I got the answer already.

Answer (score 2):

```
Date now = new Date();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO your_table(a, b, update_time) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
ps.setObject(1, a);
ps.setObject(2, b);
ps.setDate(3, now);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to parameterize the date code:

`insert (a, b, update_time) values (?, ?, now() - interval 10 second)`

Now it only takes two parameters and the date will be handled on the server.  I've had timezone issues between JDBC and MySQL concerning daylight savings time.  Be careful!